# JavaScript URL Hash detect id number

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write regex in this code to detect id on url like this: `http://example.com/#1`

```
var url = "http://example.com/#1";
var id = ; // id naumber (any date after hash 0, 00, 0000...)
if (window.location.hash == "#" + id + "") {
 alert("your id is : " + id + "");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Also, not sure what jQuery has to do with this, and you don't need the `+ ""` at the end of those string concatenations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
/#(\d+)/
```

the id is captured in group 1

```
var url = "http://example.com/#1";
var id = /#(\d+)/;
if (url.match(id)) {
     alert(url.match(id)[1]);
}
```